# Puppet provider changes (rabbitmq module)

Tags: rabbitmq, puppet

I'm working on some changes to:
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq/
I haven't worked much with rspec or with puppet types / providers, so it's been slow going. Haven't had much input via their ticket system or in Github, so just wanted to get some advice in terms of the design changes.

Basically, the module doesn't currently support multiple bindings with the same source / destination / vhost combo, but different routing keys.

I had a (mostly) working fix that was backwards compatible involving making routing_key work as either a string or array (https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-3679)

However, this doesn't work too well, because the existing provider expects the resource to be unique, and seems to assume a predictable mapping between the title of the resource and the

I had thought about making the title and name attributes different from each other, or even completely abstracting the name / title from the attributes that must be unique:

```
  rabbitmq_binding { 'exchange1@queue1@host3-1':
    name             => 'exchange1@queue1@host3',
    destination_type => 'queue',
    routing_key      => 'routingkey1',
    ensure           => present,
  }

  rabbitmq_binding { 'exchange1@queue1@host3-2':
    name             => 'exchange1@queue1@host3',
    destination_type => 'queue',
    routing_key      => 'routingkey2',
    ensure           => present,
  }
```

The actual rabbitmqctl output that self.instances is collecting for each vhost (in an example where there are two routing keys for same source / dest / vhost combo (no vhost in this example) looks like:

```
foo.bar.exchange    exchange        axs.bar.baz.queue       queue   axs.bar.baz.key       []
foo.bar.exchange    exchange        axs.bar.baz.queue       queue   axs.bar.baz.published.key       []
```

I'd rather not try to encode the routing key in the title / name attribute of the resource, but is it possible to have routing_key also tied to the resource (presumably by updating the exists? method as well as self.instances)? What would be the best things to check in unit tests for this (I already have an acceptance test), and how can I modify lib/puppet/provider/rabbitmq_binding/rabbitmqadmin.rb to support this?

Or do I just need to encode the routing key in the name as well, which just seems really ugly, and would also make backwards compatibility more difficult?

rabbitmq_binding { 'exchange1@queue1@host3@routingkey':

or

rabbitmq_binding { 'exchange1@queue1@/#routingkey':

Comment: So this is a new type or modifications to the type and it is clashing with the default provider?

Comment: I'm trying to accommodate multiple bindings with the same name / host / vhost (but different routing keys). The module doesn't seem to make that possible, even if you set '$title' to something unique (vs. $name). I'm not sure it's clashing so much as that I'm not sure a) what the cleanest and least disruptive way is to allow a user to specify multiple bindings with same (user@queue@vhost) combination, and b) how to effect my changes in the existing type / provider (lib/puppet/provider/rabbitmq_binding/rabbitmqadmin.rb / lib/puppet/type/rabbitmq_binding.rb)

Comment: Ok let me try this again. I don't know anything about RabbitMQ, but I do know how to write code for Puppet types and providers. What are you trying to do here in terms of pure Puppet code extensions? In the mean time, I can go stare at your code and guess.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was hard to understand The module defines a resource that's currently keyed on a combination of x@y@z, making the assumption that there will only ever be one x@y@z "binding" resource. I want to add support for >1 x@y@z, which you normally could do just by having $title be unique and having $name be the same for >1 resource... however, the code that collects the resources on the system to compare to also keys on x@y@z, so supporting this will also require changing the way the module thinks about or names resources internally. Does that help in more general terms?

Comment: So right now for this resource I assume `$title` is aliased to `$name`, so you are having concerns over whether you can just refactor the module to that extent to allow the unique `$title`. Yeah that would be up to the module maintainer, and it sounds like they are not getting back to you so it might be abandoned.

Comment: Well, I need to hack the module to allow this one way or another for internal use; since I'm doing it anyway, I'd prefer to do it in the cleanest possible way (while preserving backwards compatibility), and submit a pull request in case the feature is useful to someone else. The module is currently maintained (I've had other PRs merged in recent memory, and my Puppet ticket about the issue was marked as 'accepted'), it's just not super active. I'd rather contribute a fix if I'm able, than to just ask someone else to fix it.

Comment: Also, it's not just the $name / $title thing, currently, all the unique information about the resource is encoded directly in the $name / $title; I want to tie one other piece of information to that (which both the definition of the resource and the collected information about the resource already has).